# Maximizing minimum in z3

Tags: z3, z3py

I want to find the n-dimensional point `(x1...xn)` in integer space that satisfies some properties, while also maximizing the minimum distance between x and any element of a collection of m (pre-defined/constant) n-dimensional points `(z11...z1n, z21...z2n... zm1...zmn)`.  Is there a way to do this using Z3?

Answer (score 2):

Sure. See: https://rise4fun.com/Z3/tutorial/optimization

The above link talks about the SMTLib interface, but the same is also available from the Python interface as well. (And from most other bindings to Z3.)

Note that optimization is largely for linear properties. If you have non-linear terms, you might want to formulate them so that a linear-counter-part can be optimized instead. Even with non-linear terms, you might get good results, impossible to know without trying.

Comment: Thanks for the tip!  I guess where I'm confused is that I have one level of minimization going on which is essentially a constraint: `minDist = minimum([dist(x,z1), dist(x, z2)... dist(x,zm)])`, where x is a variable and the z's are constants, and then I want to do `optimizer.maximize(minDist)`.  How do I specify that minDist must be equal to the minimum of all those distances in order to maximize that minimum?

Comment: @lightning this is a *max-min* problem, what you want is to minimize a fresh `obj` variable s.t. for all `i` in `[1, N]` it holds that `obj_i <= obj` (big and of constraints) and there exists an `i` in `[1, N]` s.t. `obj <= obj_i` (big_or of constraints). Each `obj_i` does not need to be separately encoded as an objective but it suffices to encode it as a simple term.

Comment: Patrick's suggestion sounds right. If you post the code you tried and what problem you ran into, it would be much easier to understand what you are trying to do.